# h2o.ai - Flow UI not detecting date formatting to convert to Time

Tags: h2o

I am using `h2o`'s `flow ui` to uplaod a csv file to train a model on. When I upload the file and edit the column types before parsing, this is what I am setting a date column to:

[image]

After parsing, the data summary shows that all of the date column values are 'missing' and viewing the data with the `view data` button shows that they are indeed blanks (.).

Looking [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/faq/data.html) for acceptable date formats, it says that:

> "The first format is for dates formatted as yyyy-MM-dd. Year is a four-digit number, the month is a two-digit number ranging from 1 to 12, and the day is a two-digit value ranging from 1 to 31. This format can also be followed by a space and then a time (specified below)."

I have tried this format with and without (see image above) leading zeros for single digit numbers and still have the same result that h2o parses the date fields and blank, like this:

[image]

What is happening here and how can I fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: are you importing the file from excel? If you are try changing the column type in excel from time to string. If you set that column to a string type, H2O should interpret the `06/07/2015` correctly. The problem is likely that you are converting an enum type column to a time type column.

Comment: @Lauren I am importing the file from a .csv, but I did create the .csv from excel, which I used to format the dates to get them in the yyyy/mm/dd format.

Comment: okay a workaround would be to keep the same look but change the type to text. I have filed a bug in the meantime to see why H2O is interpreting excel's 'date' as an enum https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4844

Comment: @Lauren Thanks. I don't know why it is doing this now, when I trained a previous model using similar "date" data and it worked fine (`h2o` successfully converted the time data into epoch-timestamps )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In the docs mentioned in original post, it is specified that the dates should be `yyyy-mm-dd`. I was inputing the date data into `h2o` in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`. Changing the date info to the `yyyy-mm-dd` format seems to have fixed the problem (verifying that the first two dates map correctly to the first two output *epoch* time stamps).

Comment: h2o should be able to read yyyy/mm/dd this format but glad to see you found a work around.