# H2O Flow date issue and split

Tags: h2o

I am using H2O Flow when I upload the time series data, it convert the date to a number such as 1.07317E+12.I have used 2004-02-01 and 01/02/2004. I don't know how to fix this problem. I saw some note given blow but it did not help.

[h2o.ai - Flow UI not detecting date formatting to convert to Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848439/h2o-ai-flow-ui-not-detecting-date-formatting-to-convert-to-time)

Second issues, h20 flow split frame shuffle the data automatically. Is there anyway to stop it?. I know in R we can put shuffle= FALSE. But how can do it in H2O Flow as it create the problem for times series data when splitting into train and test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fine control over how your data is split, I would recommend using the H2O R or Python API. Currently, Flow only has the option to do a random split.

Flow is converting your time column to milliseconds since the Unix Epoch. In the Python and R API there has been an update so that when you view your frame you see a more human readable format.

If you'd like to see these features (more ways to split data frames and your original time format), you can create JIRA tickets here:  http://jira.h2o.ai. H2O-3 is open source and takes feature requests from the community.

But again, the fastest option is to use the Python or R API, since the functionality you'd like exists there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good input. I think it will be very useful if they add option to control the shuffle in h2o flow.

Comment: no problem! were you able to create the JIRA tickets for your two issues? Instructions on how to create JIRA tickets can be found here:https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3#21-issue-tracking-and-feature-requests.

Comment: Thank once again for sharing the link. I don't have experience with JIRA tickets but I shall try for it. About the date issue, I can fix it in R with the following commands    test$date <- as.POSIXct(test$date/ 1000, origin="1970-01-02")
test$date <- format(as.POSIXct(test$date,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),format='%m/%d/%Y'). But I could not fix the split issue of H2O Flow.

Comment: if you are using the latest version of H2O, you shouldn't have to fix the date format, it should be handled automatically. But yes, if you are using an older version you may still see the issue. It would be awesome if you could create the JIRA for flow for the time issue and the split issue. thanks again!

Comment: I am using h2o-3.26.0.2 and I think this is latest version. As the mentioned that date should in this format 2004-02-01. But date issue is still there.